# How to get the html5 text box error mesage with selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I wonder about how I can use selenium webdriver to find the error message text of a html5 input box ?

[image]

```html
<input class="_input--inputElement--2mQgjB0b theme--inputElement--2WvFsoYo" role="input" type="text" value="" xpath="1">
<span class="_input--bar--1Z4XOfUq theme--bar--fT1WI7br" xpath="1"></span>
<span class="_input--error--1ss75RVV theme--error--1p4yC2ps" xpath="1">Required</span>
```

I tried different way but none seems working!!

```
String Emessage = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),\'Required\')]")).getAttribute("Required");

String Emessage = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Required')]")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Xpath - "//*[contains(@class,'_input--error') and contains(@class,'theme--error')]"

Comment: @Akshhay, Thanks for your reply. But this doesn't work for me